# select 2 + get value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am facing a issue that I want the select value on click event. i tried with `change` event but I get all values comma separated instead of current value.

What I want to do is, Suppose there are multiple options with a `All` option. So if a user select `All` option then it should clear all selected option and only `All` option will display.

I have tried below codes

```
 $(".chzn-select").on('select2:selecting', function () {
   var st = ($(this).select2('val'));
 }
```

it show `null` on first click.

And

```
 $(".chzn-select").on('change', function () {
   var st = ($(this).select2('val'));
 }
```

show all values in comma separated format. There is no example I found of `onclick` event with `select2` JS. Here is the list of [events](https://select2.github.io/options.html#events)

HTML

```
<select name="country[]" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select country" class="form-control chzn-select" required="required" id="country">
     <option disabled="disabled" value="1">Abu Dhabi</option>
     <option value="2">Dubai</option>
     <option disabled="disabled" value="3">Singapore</option>
     <option disabled="disabled" value="4">Thailand</option>
     <option value="8">Afghanistan</option>
     <option value="All">All</option>
</select>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urfusion/gtew005w/)

Comment: Have you tried : `$(this).val()` ?

Comment: @R3tep : yes, it also return values such as `2,3,4,...`

Comment: Please provide your html

Comment: @urfusion check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/bayahiassem/gtew005w/11/

```
 $(".chzn-select").select2({selectOnClose: true}).on("select2:selecting", function(evt) {
      if(evt.params.args.data.id == 'All') {
        $(".chzn-select").val(null).trigger("change");
      } else {
        $('.chzn-select > option[value=All]').prop("selected", false);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry wronf fiddle :) here is the one ; https://jsfiddle.net/bayahiassem/gtew005w/7/

Comment: select all then other country. you will found the issue

Comment: What issue, you said that you want to clear all selected options if the All option is selected? My code does that (https://jsfiddle.net/bayahiassem/gtew005w/7/)

Comment: You didn't indicate what to do if the user select All then select another option?!

Comment: its commonsense , if you selected all country option do you allow user to enter other countries as well, if yes then what is the use of that option

Comment: There is no commonsense here :D it depends on your need, so, what do you want the behavior to be, when All already selected then we select something else? Remove the All option ?

Comment: yep, that's should be the flow. :D

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you.
If i correct.

```
$(this).select2('val').find(':selected');
```

Comment: TypeError: ":selected" is not a function

Comment: $(this).find(':selected'); check this

Comment: If there are other entries then it will return others too.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. It will you give the current selected item(s) - hold ctrl for multiple selections

```js
$(function () {
  $(".chzn-select").on('change', function (evt) {
    $('#selected').text('Selected: ' + ($(this).val()))
  })
})
```

```css
select {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country[]" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select country" class="form-control chzn-select" required="required" id="country">
     <option disabled="disabled" value="1">Abu Dhabi</option>
     <option value="2">Dubai</option>
     <option disabled="disabled" value="3">Singapore</option>
     <option disabled="disabled" value="4">Thailand</option>
     <option value="8">Afghanistan</option>
     <option value="All">All</option>
</select>

<div id="selected"></div>
```

Comment: I want to clear all options is `All` option is selected.

Comment: If `All` option selected then previous entries will remove from the list and only `All` option will display.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work,

```
 $(".chzn-select").select2({selectOnClose: true});
 $(".chzn-select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    if($.inArray('All',$(this).val()) != -1){
    $(this).val('All').trigger("change"); 
  }
 });
```

Replace your js code with this, it will work.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gtew005w/9/) link for working code.